# SQL read data from table in vb

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to get a single field back from the data. (I am searching by a primary key so I should get 0 or 1 answer). Please help. The table that I am querying has one entry with user = someone, input to several columns with the ans column having "a good answer"

---

#### Code:

```
Dim reader As SqlDataReader
Dim par As SqlParameter
Dim result As String
   
Dim sqlconn As SqlConnection
sqlconn = New SqlConnection("....")
sqlconn.Open()

Dim sqlcmd As SqlCommand
sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("Select Ans From Test Where User = @auser", sqlconn)

par = New SqlParameter
par.ParameterName = "auser"
par.Value = Textbox1.Text

sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(par)
  
reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()

result = reader.GetString(0)

''//output to label
label1.Text = result
```

Comment: invalid attempt to read when no data is present

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the data reader first to place it on the first row.

So instead of

```
reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()    
result = reader.GetString(0)
```

You'd insert the Read() method like so:

```
reader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()    
if reader.Read() then '' <<<<< newly inserted code
    result = reader.GetString(0)
end if
```

Comment: not exactly what i want... but no error! a step in the right direction! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
''// using statement will guarantee the object is closed and disposed
''// even if an exception occurs
Using sqlconn As New SqlConnection("...."), _
      sqlcmd As  New SqlCommand("Select Ans From Test Where User = @auser", sqlconn)

    ''// you can create, add, and set the value for a parameter all on one line
    sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@auser", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = Textbox1.Text

    ''//wait as long as possible to open the connection
    sqlconn.Open() 

    ''// if you're only getting the first column of the first row, use execute scalar
    label1.Text = CString(sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar())

End Using
```